# How to print a DT with different digits for columns?

Tags: r, data.table

In the toy example below, how can I print the data.table with different digits for `V1`, `V2` and `V3`.

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(2020)
library(data.table)
 
x <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(10*3), 10))
print(x, digits=2)
       V1     V2     V3
 1:  0.38 -0.853  2.174
 2:  0.30  0.909  1.098
 3: -1.10  1.196  0.318
 4: -1.13 -0.372 -0.073
 5: -2.80 -0.123  0.834
 6:  0.72  1.800  0.199
 7:  0.94  1.704  1.298
 8: -0.23 -3.039  0.937
 9:  1.76 -2.289 -0.147
10:  0.12  0.058  0.110
```

Comment: But why do you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is possible to do this keeping the data as numeric but here is a trick using regular expressions.

```
set.seed(2020)
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(10*3), 10))
digits <- c(2, 3, 4)

x[, Map(function(x, y) sub(sprintf('(.*\\..{%s}).*', y), '\\1', x), .SD, digits)]

#       V1     V2      V3
# 1:  0.37 -0.853  2.1743
# 2:  0.30  0.909  1.0981
# 3: -1.09  1.196  0.3182
# 4: -1.13 -0.371 -0.0731
# 5: -2.79 -0.123  0.8342
# 6:  0.72  1.800  0.1987
# 7:  0.93  1.703  1.2978
# 8: -0.22 -3.038  0.9367
# 9:  1.75 -2.288 -0.1474
#10:  0.11  0.058  0.1104
```

Using `sprintf` we create a pattern to extract different number of digits as defined in `digits` for each column. For example, for 1st value in `digits` i.e 2 the pattern would become

```
sprintf('(.*\\..{%s}).*', y)
#[1] "(.*\\..{2}).*"
```

meaning extract everything until a `"."` and 2 characters after it. Similarly we do this for other columns.

Comment: Although the combination of `Map` and `sub(sprintf(...))` seems to work, it trunctates the values directly.  Could it reach the `round` results with pre-specified digits?

Comment: @zengchao It works similar way with `round` : `x[, Map(function(x, y) round(x, y), .SD, digits)]`

Comment: Yep, you are right. I tried a similar manner. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Motivated by Ronak, the below solution works.

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(2020)
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(10*3), 10))
digits <- 2:4
x[, mapply(round, .SD, digits)]

         V1     V2      V3
 [1,]  0.38 -0.853  2.1744
 [2,]  0.30  0.909  1.0982
 [3,] -1.10  1.196  0.3182
 [4,] -1.13 -0.372 -0.0731
 [5,] -2.80 -0.123  0.8343
 [6,]  0.72  1.800  0.1988
 [7,]  0.94  1.704  1.2978
 [8,] -0.23 -3.039  0.9367
 [9,]  1.76 -2.289 -0.1474
[10,]  0.12  0.058  0.1104
```

Comment: For this purpose, a similar way to get a data.table is `x[, lapply(.SD, round, digits)]`.